# Converting java to kotlin -- streams

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin, and not know it properly. I have a piece of code in Java:

```
  private static Signature[] createSignatures(String... encodedSignatures) {
    return Arrays.stream(encodedSignatures)
        .map(encodedSignature -> new Signature(Base64.decode(encodedSignature, Base64.DEFAULT)))
        .toArray(Signature[]::new);
  }
```

I want to convert it to Kotlin, and I have reached till here:

```
private static Signature[] createSignatures(String... encodedSignatures) {
    return Arrays.stream(encodedSignatures)
        .map(encodedSignature -> new Signature(Base64.decode(encodedSignature, Base64.DEFAULT)))
        .toArray(Signature[]::new);
  }
```

But the above doesn't work, especially the line at the end, that is, `.toArray(Signature[]::new)` is the problem. How do I solve it? What is the correct way to convert streams to array in kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by using following code:

```kotlin
private fun createSignatures(vararg encodedSignatures: String): Array<Signature> {
    return encodedSignatures
        .map { Signature(Base64.decode(it, Base64.DEFAULT)) }
        .toTypedArray()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private fun createSignatures(vararg encodedSignatures: String): Array<Signature?>? {
    return Arrays.stream(encodedSignatures)
        .map { encodedSignature -> Signature(Base64.decode(encodedSignature, Base64.DEFAULT)) }
        .toArray { _Dummy_.__Array__() }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).